# How to enable CBA for EWS managed API authentication

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, x509certificate2

Microsoft has provided a class named [ClientCertificateCredentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.clientcertificatecredentials(v=exchg.80).aspx) in EWS library. What exactly is needed for anyone to start using it? For example, is there any Exchange server side configuration required to enable CBA for EWS? Also, what should be the certificate passed to the ExchangeService object in order to authenticate the user? Should it be only the public key or both public-private keys of the cert? Not able to find any example for CBA with EWS managed API

Comment: Although its not what you need, but maybe it will help you to get started; we have done CBA for Excahnge ACtiveSync once, here is a link  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2012/11/28/configure-certificate-based-authentication-for-exchange-activesync/

Comment: Looking at it makes me think that maybe EWS, being a separate service like EAS, requires similar configuration in order to start accepting certificates for authenticating users.

Answer (score 0):

I used the sample code here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

```
var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(AppId)
    .WithTenantId(TenantId)
    .WithCertificate(certificate)
    .Build();
var authResult = cca.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
    .ExecuteAsync()
    .Result
    .AccessToken;
```

You can get your certificate via thumbprint:

```
    X509Certificate2 GetLocalCertificateByThumbprint(string thumbprint)
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert = null;
        using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine))
        {
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var certCollection = store.Certificates;
            var currentCerts = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, false);
            var signingCert = currentCerts.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
            cert = signingCert
                .OfType<X509Certificate2>()
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.NotBefore)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }

        return cert;
    }
```